# Nested if - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, nested, innerhtml

I want the code to read the input value for Bz and give a greeting along with the answer from the equation. This is what I have this far. It's not giving a 'greeting' after the computation. Help?

```
  <html>
  <body>

<form id="function" onsubmit="return false" oninput="o.value = 3.21 + (9.63 * parseInt(Bz.valueAsNumber))">
    3.21+(9.63 *<input name="Bz" type="number" step="any">) =
   <output name="o" for="intial set Bz">0</output>&nbsp;nT

</form>

<div id="mys1"></div>

<script language="JavaScript">   
 function myMath() 
 {
    var Bz;
    var greeting; 
    if(Bz>-50)
    {
         if (Bz>-30)
         {
               greeting = "None"; 
         }
         else  
         {
               greeting = "Small ";
         }
         else 
         { 
               if (Bz> -80) 
               {
                     greeting = "Mild ";
               }
               else 
               {
                     greeting = "Large ";
               }
          }
     }
 document.getElementById("mys1").innerHTML= greeting;
 };  
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's no `else..else` construction in JS, it should be `if..else..if..else`...

Comment: @Teemu There are two if statements. The indentation is all messed up.

Comment: You've got a syntax error, missing the closing `}` for the first (outer) `if` block. Please check your error console before posting, and fix your indentation.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Yep, but there is two sequential `else` blocks in the code.

Comment: @Teemu Ah yes, you're right. I think he's missing a `}` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found your problem. Bz value is not being loaded. Seting input `name` attribute will not store the value into a variable. That attribute is for form submission.

What you should do is:

```
function myMath() 
 {
    var Bz = $("input[name='Bz']").val();
    ...
    ...
    ...
 }
```

Comment: '$' is jquery. I don't have that in my script. Is there any other way to do it without jquery?

Comment: So, can't you use JQuery for some reason? [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/javascript-get-input-text-value) you can find how to target the desired input without JQuery. If you can assign an ID to it, it is just `var Bz = document.getElementById("your_input_id").value;`

Answer (score 0):

Where are you calling your function `myMath()` from? I guess it is not being fired.

Also, the way you wrote your `if`s statements is pretty ugly. This would be much nicer:

```
if(Bz>-30)
{
    greeting = "Small";
}
else if(Bz>-50)
{
    greeting = "Mid ";
}
else if(Bz>-80)
{
    greeting = "Large";
}
else
{
    greeting = "None";
}
```

Beware that I wrote this trying to guess what greeting message you actually want. Notice that if the first condition is satisfied, the other conditions will not even be checked at all.

Comment: I forgot one line of code after the equation:
<br><input type="button" value="Predict" name="myButton" onClick="myMath()" >

Comment: Ok, then the problem is that your `if` are wrong. If you explain me what greeting you want in which case I would write the ifs for you. Also, are there any errors in your console? If there are you should add them to your post too

Comment: There are no errors showing after I took it out of the format I had initially. 
For Bz > -80, I wanted it to greet Large. For Bz > -50, Mild. Bz > -30, Small. It was suppose to analysis the input and greet determining the range it fit best with.

Comment: @maebee_me Alright, I have fixed the code in the answer. Please check it out. If the value is any value bigger than -30, greeting is small. If it is between -50 and -30, the value is mid. If it is between -80 and -50, it is Large. If it is less than -80(Because it doesn't fit in any of the other cases), then the greeting is "None". I hope this helped you, please let me know if you still can't do it.

Comment: regardless of the number, the only thing that shows is 'None'.

Comment: I added a new answer, please check it out and upvote me if it works.